# Clean URL false positive/negative?

Tags: uri

I was developing on my local machine (Mac OS X) and moved to a VPS with CentOS 6.5.  Problem I'm having is with clean urls.  It was working fine on the local machine.  However on the vps server, I'm seeing something strange.  When I go to enable it, I can go to the config page with clean url (example.com/admin/config/search/clean-urls) and the checkbox is enabled.  When I check it and save it, the page refreshes with "The configuration option have been saved." but the checkbox is not checked.  I can repeat this process.  If I look into variables table, I see the following.

```
+-----------+-------+
| name      | value |
+-----------+-------+
| clean_url | i:1;  |
+-----------+-------+
```

I cleared cache manually (via MySQL) and through Drupal interface. I checked reports and it is all clean. I looked at logs, but they don't seem to show anything related to this issue.  The effect of this is that all URLs generated are ?q=..

Any ideas on what I should look for next?

Comment: Is the Mod Rewrite module installed and working? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Yes it is enabled and working.  I can goto a page without using query string like http://example.com/admin/config/search/clean-urls

Comment: Are you sure settings.php is not overriding the value of that variable with `$conf['clean_url']`?